# track changes in table nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

How can I track changes in table, using node js? For connection I use Sequelize. 
The task is watch user data changes and emmit event to frontend if there was changes. I use socket io, and don`t wont use timeout. Is there the way to track event like 'table field xxx where user_id = yyy was changed' and got new field value.

Comment: It will heavily depend of the database, and teh API you use for that database. Node.js only can t do that if the DB don t allow it.

Comment: Sequelinze, MySQL. Maybe there are other ORM, that can resolve this problem?

Comment: Are the data added/edited by node.js via Sequelize or by another program/script?

Comment: Data edited by another program

Comment: Then you ll have to make the other program notify node.js of a change in the data, and where to look. You can try to put [hooks in Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/), but it  seems to only work inside sequelize and not watching the db itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooks in sequelize. 
In your conf/connection.js you can define global hooks. In this way you can intercept everything.

hooks definition:

```
const hooks = {
beforeBulkUpdate: (options) => {
    options.individualHooks = true;
    return;
},
beforeBulkDestroy: (options) => {
    options.individualHooks = true;
    return;
},
beforeCreate: (instance, options) => {
    sails.log.info(("%s %s"), 'beforeCreate', instance.$modelOptions.tableName);

    return;
},
beforeUpdate: (instance, options) => {
    sails.log.info(("%s %s"), 'beforeUpdate', instance.$modelOptions.tableName);

    var payload = {
        before: instance._previousDataValues,
        after: instance.dataValues,
        changed: instance._changed
    };
    ----> here you can write on the web socket
    return;
},
beforeDestroy: (instance, options) => {
    sails.log.info(("%s %s"), 'beforeDestroy', instance.$modelOptions.tableName);

    return;
}

}
```

connection:

```
mydb: {
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    options: {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'myhost',
        logging: true,
        define: {
            hooks: hooks
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: This only works, when the same sequelize instance changes the data. How about observe changes which happens from another App or on the Database itself? Is that only with polling possible?